# TD trivial fixes taking forever

Tags: html, css, height

I spent 2 days trying to figure out why this td has bigger height than it should, and I know it might be something trivial that I can hardly observe.

this is how the HTML looks in the inspector:
[image]

Plese note that height is 50px but the td doesnt respond to it

[image]

even though the image height is 50px :)

[image]

where does the 5px come from ?

Comment: Can you upload all this to a proper [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: I tried but I couldnt, it didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple demo of the problem:

```
<table><tr><td style="border: solid red 1px; padding:0"><img 
  src=http://lorempixel.com/54/50/ alt=""></table>
```

With the cell border drawn, you can see that there is space below the image. It’s reserved for descenders of letters, even though no real letters are present – the content is still taken as text.

The simplest fix is to add the following to the style sheet:

```
td img { display: block; }
```

This causes the image to be set as a simple block, instead of being treated as an element text (a large letter, so to say) sitting on the baseline of text.

Comment: wow that was amazing :)) I didnt know that, thanks
but you know what, now td is 52px? where did the 2 come from ?:)

Comment: @Digitalfortress, the two pixels in total height come from the border, which was there just to show what’s going on; so just remove the `border` setting.

Comment: I didnt add the border styling from the start!

Comment: @Digitalfortress, if you still have 2 pixels extra, please post code (HTML and CSS) that reproduces the issue.